Django REST Authentication credentials were not provided
I'm developing an API using Django Rest Framework.
but when i'm trying to access the console gives me this error:
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_all_messages(request, user_id):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(receiver_id=user_id)
    serializer = MessageSerializer(messages, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/get-all-messages/<int:user_id>/', get_all_messages),
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [  # Corrected typo here
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

http://localhost:8000/api/token/
copy the token
I have searched but they say to change the REST_FRAMEWORK's AUTHENTICATION PERMISSIONS which I have done as you can see, but to no avail.

Can you please share the code where you're making the API call to the get_all_messages view

rest_framework_simplejwt Tokens cannot be Authenticated by rest_framework TokenAuthentication!
Use rest_framework_simplejwt JWTAuthentication to Authenticate.
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # •••
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
    # •••
}
If you want to use a different Authentication mechanism for a specific view, that’s when you use decorators like this:
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
If you don’t need it don’t use it!

I would recommend the getting started guide. [simple-jwt]
